# globas and exec in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have written code, to create variable and assign values using for loop.

```
nums = [0,1,2,3]
names = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]

for num, name in zip(nums, names):
    globals()["df"+str(num)]= names[num]
    print(exec(f'df{num}'))
```

but I am getting result as None

```
#result:

None
None
None
None
```

but even I tried to change the code with below modification, still getting the same

```
nums = [0,1,2,3]
names = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]

for num, name in zip(nums, names):
    globals()["df"+str(num)]= name
    print(exec(f'df{num}'))
```

Can some one help me to get the proper answer for this.

Note: even I used exec function in the place of name (ex: exec(f'{names[num]}') then I am getting name error.

Comment: Why not store your data as a dictionary of dataframes instead?

Comment: Usually dynamically creating variable isnt a good idea. You could try to create a dict of dataframe: `global MY_DFS = {}` and then `MY_DFS[num] = name`

Comment: `exec()` returns `None`, this is as simple as that. If you want to access the value of say `df0` just use `globals()` again or include `print()` inside `exec()` or use `eval()` instead of `exec()`.

Comment: Thanks every one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `exec` returns `None`, I don't see why you would expect otherwise.

Try changing a little bit your code to see it is working correctly, for example:

```
nums = [0,1,2,3]
names = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]

for num, name in zip(nums, names):
    globals()["df"+str(num)]= name
    exec(f'print(df{num})')
```

Outputs:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

**Update:** If you want to return something, you must use `eval`:

```
nums = [0,1,2,3]
names = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"]

for num, name in zip(nums, names):
    globals()["df"+str(num)]= name
    print(eval(f'df{num}'))
```

Outputs:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misplaced the print in your for loop, you should execute the printing of your variable, only executing the variable won't return nor print anything. This should work:

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 3]
names = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]

for num, name in zip(nums, names):
    globals()["df" + str(num)] = name
    exec(f"print(df{num})")
```